# How do you write these kind of equations with conditions?

Tags: amsmath

[image]

I want to get this kind of equation, so I put the code as below

```
    \[1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot\] \[\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}lr@{}}
      (q/p)^{z-k} & k\leq z \\
      1 & k> z \\
\end{array} 
\right. \]
```

but what I get is like below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE. Just remove the `\] \[` after `\cdot`. That way, LaTeX will see only 1 display math group.

Comment: It worked thanks a lot! @Mico

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In alternative you can use `Bmatrix`....

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot\begin{Bmatrix}
      (q/p)^{z-k} & \text{if } k\leq z\\
      1           & \text{if } k>z
\end{Bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were faster than me! (+1)

Comment: @Bernard ahaahah it is only the "fortuna" :-)..but you can choose to use \Biggl and \Biggr :-)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to removing the `\] \[` code fragment after `\cdot`, you may also want to replace the `array` enviroment with a `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment
\begin{document}
\[
1-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot
\begin{cases}
      (q/p)^{z-k} & \text{if $k\leq z$} \\
      1           & \text{if $k>z$} 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[\arraycolsep=1pt\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}\cdot
      \left\{\begin{array}{cl}(q/p)^{z-k}&\text{ if }k\leqslant z\\
             1&\text{ if }k>z\end{array}\right\}\]
\end{document}
```

then you will get this:

[image]